# Overriding the attributes key node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, nodes, soap-client

I am using SAP SOAP web service.

XML Tag

```
 <Item>
    <ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>3</ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>
    <OriginalEntryDocumentItemReferenceItemID>117000</OriginalEntryDocumentItemReferenceItemID>
    <GeneralLedgerAccountAliasCode>A-7999</GeneralLedgerAccountAliasCode>
    <BusinessTransactionCurrencyAmount currencyCode="USD">100</BusinessTransactionCurrencyAmount>
 </Item>
```

I converted the above request in node.js

```
    Item : {
        ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID : "3",
        OriginalEntryDocumentItemReferenceItemID : "117000",
        GeneralLedgerAccountAliasCode : "A-7999",
        BusinessTransactionCurrencyAmount :  {
              Amount : //This is not working
              {
                _ : 100,
                currencyCode : "USD"
              },
        }
      }
```

But I am facing the problem on below line. I am new to this language.

How does pass attribute (CurrencyCode) into node js response? How does convert below line into node js (response)?

```
   <BusinessTransactionCurrencyAmount currencyCode="USD">100</BusinessTransactionCurrencyAmount>
```

Please help me to solve this issue!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please brief it more.

Comment: @node_saini I rewrite the qus. Please help me!

Comment: Do you want to convert it like this `BusinessTransactionCurrencyAmount:{ currencyCode : "USD", Amount: 100 }`

Comment: @node_saini actually I don't know how to convert this. Just try with that method. How to convert that attribute?

Comment: @node_saini Yes I need to convert like that.